# Riot API Promise All With Fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I am trying to loop through 10 league of legends matches and for each match, call another api to get the match details. So far I have a function set up like this:

```
function getAllMatchData(ids) {
    const promises = [];
    _.take(ids, 1).forEach(id => {
        const promise = fetch(`https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v4/matches/${id}`, {
            headers: {"X-Riot-Token": token}})
        promises.push(promise);
    })
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Since the api returns 100 matches, I only take the top 10 and then create an array of promises with them. I then do this to get the results:

```
getAllMatchData(_.map(data['matches'], 'gameId')).then(results => {
     console.log(results);
}).catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
})
```

But the console log for the results don't have any json data in it. It prints an array of objects that look like this:

```
Response {
    size: 0,
    timeout: 0,
    [Symbol(Body internals)]: { body: [Gunzip], disturbed: false, error: null },
    [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
      url: 'https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v4/matches/3556728982',
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'OK',
      headers: [Headers],
      counter: 0
    }
  }
```

I am not sure where the JSON data response is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With fetch, you need to parse the response with the type of response you received.

```js
        const promise = fetch(`https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v4/matches/${id}`, {
            headers: {"X-Riot-Token": token}}).then(res => res.json())
```

In your case it's json. So it's as simple as calling `res.json()`.